# why the ready() displays the image before finishing its execution?

Tags: jquery, html

in this simple **html** page, in the `<body>` there is an **image** and a **paragraph**.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {

            alert("hello");
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <p>this is a paragraph</p>
    <img src="images/mayor.jpg" />
</body>
</html>
```

the `ready()` function by definition executes after **DOM** is loaded and before **images** are loaded. So the `alert()` should show the alert box with the text **hello** and at this point there cannot be any **images** shown till i click **OK** of the **alert box**. but when i use **chrome** or **Firefox** it shows the **image**. [this you tube video](https://youtu.be/qhWii_T_WQY) shows the issue.

However, It wont show the image if i've cleared the browsers' cache before each run. but if i'm creating a web application to use by a business client i cannot ask them to clear cache like this. Is there a way to fix this problem?

Comment: The only requirment of `ready` is that the DOM is fully loaded and ready to be manipulated. Even if the cache was cleared, the imaes could have finished loading befor dom ready is called, e.g. if you include a long loading script at the bottom of your `body`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the image is in cache, then it doesn't have to be loaded asynchronously. It can be displayed immediately when the `<img>` tag is parsed.

Comment: okay so for some reason if i don't want to display the image?

Comment: Use CSS to hide the image, and show it in the ready function.

Comment: Yeah. You can do like @Barmar said. Add an id or class to the image so that you can easily access it in javascript.

`<img src="images/mayor.jpg?v=13232" id="thisImage" style="display:none" />`

And the js code:

`$(function(){
    $('#thisImage').show();
})`

Answer (score 1):

Of course you can. Add a random number to your image src, like this:

```
<img src="images/mayor.jpg?v=13232" />
```

`13232` must be a random number on each load.

Comment: Which means the random number must be added on the server.  It seems way easier and more controllable to just have the image hidden until you want it to show.